# Why does Malloc allocate more memory than I requested?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I must define a dynamic array of struct. But when I define an array this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct user {
   int id;
   char *name;
   int *friendlist;
   int *blocklist;
   char *university;
   int age;
};

int main (void)
{
    struct user *Userlist;
    Userlist = malloc(sizeof(Userlist) * 10);
    Userlist[2815].name="Someone";
    printf("%s\n", Userlist[2815].name );
    return 0;
}
```

I defined memory for 10 Userlist structures. It stores the 2815 structure. But when I try to assign value to 2816th struct, it says "segmentation error.Core dumped".   It must store the 10 structs I allocated, But why does it store 2815 structs?

Comment: `Userlist =malloc(sizeof(Userlist) * 10);` you probably mean `Userlist =malloc(sizeof(*Userlist) * 10);`

Comment: (1) UserList is pointer. (2) you have 10 pointer to struct user.

Comment: (I moved the `return 0` outside your `main` function into it, as this error was not relevant to your question. However, you should take care to post your *exact* code -- this could not be it because it would not compile.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `malloc` call only set aside as much storage as you specified (10 elements of `struct user`).  C doesn't do any bounds checking on array accesses; the language assumes that you know how big your array is, and that you're smart enough not to go past the end of it.

Attempting to access items past the end of the array invokes *undefined behavior*, which doesn't *have* to result in a segfault or a crash.  It just so happened that the memory at index 2815 wasn't protected or being used for anything "important" (although it may have affected execution somewhere else).

For reference, here's the definition for "undefined behavior", taken from [the latest standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **3.4.3**
>
> 1 **undeﬁned behavior**
> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
> for which this International Standard imposes no requirements
>
> 2 NOTE Possible undeﬁned behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable
> results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
> environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or
> execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).
> 3 EXAMPLE An example of undeﬁned behavior is the behavior on integer overﬂow

Comment: So do I must continue like to I have only 10 struct ? @John Bode

Comment: @GismatKazimli: not "like". For all intents and purposes, you *have* allocated memory for only 10 structure members, and so you only *can* access 10 elements without running into the problems you encountered. Your program is not "simulating" memory access restricted to 10 elements, it really has.

Comment: @Jongware okey, thanks for all

Answer (score 2):

```
struct user {
   int id;
   char *name;
   int *friendlist;
   int *blocklist;
   char *university;
   int age;
};
```

You define a structure which contains 2 int values, 2 int pointers and 2 char pointers.

```
Userlist = malloc(sizeof(Userlist) * 10);// mind that malloc returns a void* so you should probably add a typecast
```

You allocate memory for an array of 10 elements of type UserList; Userlist is of type user* so basically you are allocating memory for sizeof(pointer) which on most systems is sizeof(int) - 4 bytes.
You probably want to allocate memory for an array of 10 elements of type user:

```
Userlist = (user*)malloc(sizeof(user) * 10);
```

You are still not out of the woods so to speak;  any assignment like:  `Userlist[0].name="Someone";` is still undefined behaviour because you allocate memory for the pointer but not for the buffer it points to. For this particular assignment, the compiler allocates memory for the string, only it does so on the stack, not on the heap - so be careful about this!

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

it does not malloc 2815 struct.  In fact it only mallocs 10 pointers!! (about 80 bytes on a typical system)  you are not getting the fault due to chance, not due to a compiler feature.  Hope this helps.